# how to get a model by array params from a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have a model like this:

```
model = 
    from: "a@b.com"
    id: 1
    to: [c@d.com]
```

and I have a collection containing these kind of models. The collection needs to filter by `from`. I know `_.where` an `underscore.js` function. I am using it like this:

```
fromIds = _.pluck _.where(msgs, from : login), 'msgId'
```

and need to filter by 'to' as well:

```
toIds = _.pluck _.where(msgs, to : login), 'msgId'
```

it does not work, because `to` is an array. How can I filter by `to` ? I would be grateful if someone helped me out !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At that point you need to use `_.filter`. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L240) you can see that `_.where` is just a helpful wrapper around `_.filter`. `_.where` is good for simple filtering based on primitive comparison, but anything more complex you will have to write yourself.

```
# Filter for messages that contain the target address.
matchedTo = _.filter msgs, (msg) -> _.contains msg.to, login

# Pluck as usual
toIds = _.pluck matchedTo, 'msgId'
```